# How to select random sample from 4 dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, random, sample

I have an array with shape (100,505,555,2).
I need to choose a sample with lower size in order to calculate correlation between points with size 100. So I need to choose from the second and third dimension of the array. for example get  an array of size (100,50,50,2)

I tried to use

np.random.choice or np.random.Generator.choice but not successful.

can you please help??

I tried this to select 50*50 samples from 2nd and 3rd dimensions to calculate covariance between each of the randomly selected indices:

```
cov_arr=[]
for i in np.arange(1,50):
    for j in np.arange(1,50):
        ran_i = np.random.randint(555)
        ran_j = np.random.randint(504)
        covariance =np.cov(data[:,ran_i,ran_j,1],
                         data[:,ran_i,ran_j,1])
        cov_arr.append((ran_i,ran_j,covariance[0][1]))
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What did you try? What result did you expect and what did you get?

Comment: the first dimension is time index, the 2nd and 3d ones are locations (x,y) and the last one is velocity of particle in two direction horizontal and vertical.

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for index out of bounds!

In `np.random.randint` you have to remove the size of your **window_size** from the upper bound of your random variable.
In this way your window is always included in your matrix.

The following code calculates the covariance between two windows selected randomly for each time t.

```
data = np.random.rand(100,505,555,2)

window_size = 50
cov_arr=[]
for t in range(data.shape[0]): #for each time t
    ran_i = np.random.randint(0, data.shape[1]-window_size)
    ran_j = np.random.randint(0, data.shape[2]-window_size)
    covariance =np.cov(data[t,ran_i:ran_i+window_size,ran_j:ran_j+window_size,1],
                     data[t,ran_i:ran_i+window_size,ran_j:ran_j+window_size,1]) #you probably do not want '1' here
    cov_arr.append((ran_i,ran_j,covariance[0][1]))
```